# Returning a "computed" column from a query in SQLAlchemy

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Say I have the following classes:

```
class Basket(db.Model):
    id = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)

class Fruit(db.Model):
    id = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    basket_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('basket.id'))
```

I would like to do a query on the `fruit` table that returns among its result a "computed" column called `in_basket` that is `True` if a fruit's `basket_id` is in the list of basket ids `[1, 2, 3]` and `False` otherwise.

Is there a way to do this in SQLAlchemy?  I'm using flask-sqlalchemy and Postgres 9.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Should be straightforward using [`case`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/core/expression_api.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.case) expression:

```
class Fruit(...):
    ...
    def is_in_basket(self, busket_list):
        return self.basket_id in busket_list

def get_fruits(basket_list):
    from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import case
    xpr = case([(Fruit.basket_id.in_(basket_list), True),], else_ = False).label("in_basket")
    qry = session.query(Fruit, xpr)
    fruits = []
    for fruit, in_basket in qry:
        fruit.in_basket = in_basket # assign value to a Fruit property (as per comment below)
        fruits.append(fruit)
    return fruits

fruits = get_fruits(my_basket_list)
for f in fruits:
    print f, f.in_basket, f.is_in_basket(my_basket_list)
```

Comment: Many thanks Van.  This looks very interesting.  How would I define a column on Fruits so that Fruits.query always returned a computed column called Fruit.in_basket?  (The column definition would need to look up basket_list when the query was run, though, since basket_list is dynamic.)

Comment: I honestly do not see purpose of this. When you query `Fruit` objects, you can filter on the `in_basket`. However, if you already have objects in-memory, the `in_basket` is just `def in_basket(self, blist): return self.basket_id in blist`. Also, nothing prevents you to post-process the query and do `fruit.in_basket = in_basket` in the loop (see above - updated an answer)

Comment: Thanks Van.  I'm aware of @property (e.g., your in_basket method), but making it a "virtual" (computed) field is forcing me to add logic elsewhere.  I was wondering if it was possible to do this readily in the database itself.

Comment: Well, the *def get_fruits(...)* does just that: making the calculation on the database. The fact that your *condition* of basket_ids is completely external would not allow you to do that as you wish though... Anyways, if you find a better solution, please share. Thanks!